# Converting time stamp to minutes elapsed in Python

Tags: python, datetime

I am making a news blog for my project in which I have to display time under the news title as x minutes ago etc.

From the RSS feed of the news, I have the time stamp in the form of a string. For example:

timestamp = 'Tue, 12 Feb 2013 07:43:09 GMT'

I am trying to find the difference between this timestamp and the present time using datetime module in python. But for some reason it gives error:

ValueError: astimezone() cannot be applied to a naive datetime

I'll appreciate if somebody can point me in the right direction. Below is my attempt in Python:

```
from datetime import datetime
from pytz import timezone
timestamp = 'Tue, 12 Feb 2013 07:43:09 GMT'  
t = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %Z')
now_time = datetime.now(timezone('US/Pacific'))
# converting the timestamp to Pacific time
t_pacific = t.astimezone(timezone('US/Pacific'))   # get error here
diff = t_pacific - t
```

Thanks!
Prakhar

Comment: Are you running into particular problems calculating the difference without the time zone conversions (i.e. Does it work correctly if you skip the calls to timezone)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your example had a few problems (I see you've fixed them now):

- First line should be:

  ```
  from datetime import datetime
  ```
- It looks as though you're missing a closing parenthesis on the 4th line:

  ```
  now_time = datetime.now(timezone('US/Pacific')
  ```
- What is `timezone()`? Where does that come from?

You don't really need to mess with timezones, I don't think — just use GMT (UTC). How about something more like this:

```
from datetime import datetime
timestamp = 'Tue, 12 Feb 2013 07:43:09 GMT'  
t = datetime.strptime(timestamp, '%a, %d %b %Y %I:%M:%S %Z')
t_now = datetime.utcnow()
diff = t_now - t
```

Comment: Thanks for finding the mistake. I updated the code. But i still get the error.

Comment: Got it!! Thanks a lot Craig. I was messing up by conversion.

Answer (score 2):

The problem here is that `t` does not have a timezone—that's what the error message means by "naive datetime". From [the docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html):

> There are two kinds of date and time objects: “naive” and “aware”… An aware object has sufficient knowledge of… time zone and daylight savings time information… A naive object does not…

You can verify that it's naive by doing this:

```
print(t.tzinfo)
```

The answer will be `None`.

As the [`astimezone` docs](http://docs.python.org/2/library/datetime.html#datetime.datetime.astimezone) say:

> `self` must be aware (`self.tzinfo` must not be `None`, and `self.utcoffset()` must not return `None`).

The `strptime` function *always* generates a naive datetime.

You can fix this in various ways:

- First convert `t` to a GMT datetime instead of a naive one, and then your conversion to `'US/Pacific'` will work.

As the docs say, "If you merely want to attach a time zone object tz to a datetime dt without adjustment of date and time data, use `dt.replace(tzinfo=tz)`." Since you know the time is in UTC, just `replace` the empty tz with UTC, and you've got an aware time.

- Convert to PST with a different mechanism than `astimezone`, on which will assume UTC or which allows you to specify the source.

There are various alternatives out there, but you're already using `pytz`, so see [its documentation](http://pytz.sourceforge.net).

- Convert `now_time` to UTC instead of converting `t` to PST.

The last one is probably the simplest and best for most use cases. Since you've only got `now_time` in PST because you explicitly asked for it that way, all you have to do is not do that (or explicitly ask for `'GMT'` instead of `'US/Pacific'`). Then you can just do your date arithmetic on UTC times.

If you need to display final results in PST, it's still often better to do the arithmetic in UTC, and convert at the end. (For example, you can have two times that are an hour apart, but have the same value in Pacific, because of 1am on DST day being repeated twice; that won't be an issue if you stay in UTC all the time.)

Comment: Thanks @abarnert for the awesome explanation. I will take your advice and do the arithmetic in UTC.

Comment: @PrakharMehrotra: Of course Craig McQueen already gave that advice before I finished writing my answer… but you already accepted his answer, so all is as it should be.